# How to perform sed replacement on range of lines?

Tags: sed

I want sed to read through a text file, find a specific series of numbers, and replace them with another series of numbers.

However, I only want it to do that for a given range such as lines 200-220.
I can find pages on here about how to do one or the other, not both.

My attempts so far look like:

```
sed -i '200,220 !/1 2 3 4 5 \replacement numbers' file
```

I'm probably approaching this completely incorrectly, but hey ho.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were close

```
sed -i '200,220 s/1 2 3 4 5 /replacement numbers/' file
```

in 200-220 range this will replace '1 2 3 4 5 ' with other stuff only once (per line). If more replacements needed than added g here ...numbers/g' file  and so on